# Internal object representation when designing JSON apis

Tags: java, json, web-services, jackson

I've got an object design question.

I'm building a json api in Java. My system uses pojos to represent json objects and translates them from json to pojo using Jackson. Each object needs to take different forms in different contexts, and I can't decide whether to create a bunch of separate classes, one for each context, or try to make a common class work in all circumstances.

Let me give a concrete example.

The system has users. The api has a service to add, modify and delete uses. There is a table of users in a database. The database record looks like this:

```
{
  id: 123, // autoincrement
  name: "Bob",
  passwordHash: "random string",
  unmodifiable: "some string"
}
```

When you POST/add a user, your pojo should not include an id, because that's autogenerated. You also want to be able to include a password, which gets hashed and stored in the db.

When you PUT/update a user, your pojo shouldn't include the unmodifiable field, but it must include the id, so you know what user you're modifying.

When you GET/retrieve the user, you should get all fields except the passwordHash.

So the pojo that represents the user has different properties depending on whether you're adding, updating, or retrieving the user. And it has different properties in the database.

So, should I create four different pojos in my system and translate among them? Or create one User class and try to make it look different in different circumstances, using Jackson views or some other mechanism?

I'm finding the latter approach really hard to manage.

Comment: Why have POJOs at all?  Just use Maps.

Comment: Pojos are helpful because they make it easy to document the inputs and outputs of your web services.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should create only one `POJO` - `User` which has all needed properties. And now you should decide whether your `API` is rigorous or lenient. If your `API` is rigorous it should return error when it receives wrong `JSON` data. In lenient version `API` can skip superfluous (unnecessary) properties.

Before I will provide an example, let me change the 'passwordHash' property to 'password'.

**Add new user/POST**
`JSON` data from client:

```
{
  id: 123,
  name: "Bob",
  password: "random string",
  unmodifiable: "some string"
}
```

Rigorous version can return for example something like this:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorType": 1001,
            "message": "Id field is not allowed in POST request."
        }
    ]
}
```

Lenient version can return for example something like this:

```
{
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "warnings": [
        "Id field was omitted."
    ]
}
```

For each `CRUD` method you can write a set of unit tests which will be holding information which way you choose and what is allowed and what is not.

Comment: I agree with this. One of the problems with tightly specifying data schemas (e.g. with XML Schema or even JSON schema) is that validation decisions aren't inherent in the data, but are part of the process. Validation depends on what you are doing with the data. Hence in this case, better to put the validation into the process level (the API) rather than the data level (the POJOs). Postel's Law applies well here.